# Delete only messages based on search not conversations

Tags: gmail

Is there a way to delete only messages coming from specified address, leaving any followup answers (conversations) in the mailbox?

I'm receiving a lot of messages from automated ticket system.
I would like to delete all messages coming from that system, but I would like to keep any answers from real people in my mailbox.

Alternatively I would be happy with deleting only messages from specific address that do not have any other messages in conversation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could experiment with turning off the conversations setting. Note this

1. Click on the gear symbol in the upper right corner
2. Select Mail settings from the drop down
3. In the conservation view section on the General Settings tab select "Conversation view off"

Then delete the messages you don't want.

I assume that you will have to delete the messages, or they will reattach themselves to the conversations.

You will now have to turn "Conversation view on" using the earlier procedure

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you!.